# How to display different record types as related list under an object?

Tags: page-layout, record-type

We have a 'Policy' object, with several record types

- Air
- Car
- Type
  etc...

They all have a lookup to 'Account', but each has it's own set of custom fields, that's unique to the policy.

I want to display on the Account page (lightning page) the different policies, but each in it's own related list.

One solution would be to create multiple policy objects, to overcome the request, however, the handling of the policies are all the same, so it does not make sense.

Is it possible to display the related list per record type, on the Account page?

Comment: Have you looked on AppExchange?  There are several components available for related lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement  you need related list  with filtered records based on recordtype.
As of now, filtered related list is not possible by standard salesforce functionality.
please see this idea:
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brbg

Alternate Approach   would be to create a customizable lightning datatable using lwc or aura   or you can use already prebuilt solutions.

please refer to this thread and prebuilt solutions mentioned by David Reed for more details:

[Filter in Related List using fields from related record](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/258813/filter-in-related-list-using-fields-from-related-record)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible with the OOTB options. You have to use some customization to add your filters. Please refer this [issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/258813/filter-in-related-list-using-fields-from-related-record). Also there is [this idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brbg) already submitted. Hopefully it will soon be available as GA.

Hope it helps you. Good luck.